# Magento 2.3.6 search result page no product images

Tags: product-images, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, search-result

I'm trying to fix a an issue in a store for a customer without success..
Website prochet1861.com is developed with Magento 2.3.6 and running Elasticsearch 7.
All work perfect (categories, advanced search, quick search, etc) but I have a problem with search result page, it show me correct results but products grid show placeholder images and display correct product image only on rollover.
If I try this query, for example: https://www.prochet1861.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=tazza result is a page with only thumbnails..
Main image path: https://www.prochet1861.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/it_IT/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
Rollover (correct image) Path: https://www.prochet1861.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/bb9dc070e2c11e42e26fdc86dfdfe117/s/o/sola.jpg
Product detail is OK and advanced search work perfectly... just quick search have this problem.
I have tried various solutions: REINDEX, CLEAR CACHE, REGENERATE STATIC FILES, DISABLE PORTO THEME AND SWITCH TO DEFAULT LUMA, DISABLE SOME EXTENSIONS, SWITCH TO MySQL SEARCH ENGINE... nothing fix this problem, can anybody help me?! **THANK YOU**!

Comment: Have you run the image resize command ??

Comment: Do any of the answers below resolve your problem? If so, please accept one. It helps the community. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0):

I do see, as you noted, that your client is using the Porto theme. It's odd that disabling Porto wouldn't fix your issue, but this appears to be an option you can enable/disable from admin [according to Porto's documentation](https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/):

> Go to Stores > Configuration > Porto > Porto - Settings Panel section
> to start your own design configuration. Names of all settings are
> pretty self-explanatory.
>
> ---
>
> Category View
> In this tab, you can set options for the category view page.
>
> Show Alternative Product Image: When you mouse hover on a product, you
> can see a thumbnail image. You can enable/disable this function in
> this option.

As for why disabling Porto doesn't fix this, I suppose it's *possible* that Porto registers this setting in database config, or that it's stuck in some weird cache somewhere. At any rate, I'd try this first if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Porto theme feature
In product listing page, each product is showing 2 images.
If you want to keep this feature, edit the product > in the image section, tick both image and hover_image

Answer (score 0):

I would say its not a some other issue of Magento or any other core related issue.
Images are showing fine on the category pages and its only issue creating on Search Result page.

Also, if you hover on Search Result page then also images are showing fine, it seems only issue of configuration.

Porto might have some toggle option in their Settings panel.[image]